# Drop down list of names, choose a name, copy and paste person's rows of information from one sheet to another

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to VBA and trying to make a drop down list of names(XXX, YYY, ZZZ, etc.) of people within different jobs, then you can select one name from the list, then have their rows of information for that person from Sheet7 copied and pasted to Sheet3 where the search bar is. I haven't been successful in this and would appreciate some help. I made the code more generic to the names and job for this post. Thanks in advance.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
'On Error GoTo Cleanup
Application.ScreenUpdating = False: Application.EnableEvents = False

With Sheet3
    For i = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlup).Rows To 2 Step -1
    Select Case .Cells(i, 3).Value = c
        Case "XXX", "YYY", "ZZZ", "AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD", "FFF", "GGG", "HHH", "III", "JJJ", "LLL", "MMM", "NNN"
        .Rows(i).Copy 
        End Select
With Sheet3
Dim lastrow As Long
lastrow = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row

Worksheets(i).Activate
Cells(lastrow + 1, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

End With
End With
'Cleanup:
'Application.ScreenUpdating = True: Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the problem (error?) with the current code you have?

Comment: It is not giving me an error message, but not doing anything when I click the command button after a name is selected.

Comment: `xlUp`, not `x1up` - the letter `l`, not the number `1`.

Comment: Thank you, it still did not work though

Comment: Then comment out the error handling and report back on the error thrown. Or add a `Debug.Print` to make sure that the `Case` is actually true. Do you really have data out in column CTO (yikes, that would be a nasty spreadsheet)?

Comment: `.Rows`, not `.Row` too.

Comment: This looks dodgy too `.Cells(.Rows.Count, "Job")`. What is "Job"?

Comment: Are `CTO` and `Job` named ranges? Or are you really dealing with data in those columns? @SJR if there is really data out in column JOB, wow that would be a first for spreadsheet size.

Comment: @BigBen - ha, hadn't actually occurred that could even be a column reference. Nothing would surprise me. Column 7152 in case you're interested.

Comment: Sorry, meant to change "CTO" to be "job" since that is an example of a job that is being searched for in column 3

Comment: So, the second argument of `Cells` is a *column* reference (number/letter). Sounds like you want `3` instead of `Job`? Right now you are dealing with columns CTO and JOB, so way out to the right.

Comment: Semi-off-question/topic... Why are you executing this as a command button and not a change_event when a data validation table is selecting the data?  You mention a search bar, but you have a pre-defined list of information, which would make sense as a data validation table.

Comment: This is my second project using VBA so I'm not familiar with change_event at all

Comment: So now I'm getting run-time error '9' substript out of range for the line "With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3")" but Sheet3 is the name of the worksheet where I want the data pasted.

Comment: Use the codename of the sheet - you can see it in the VBA Editor. Probably `With Sheet3` is all you need.

Comment: I want people to be able to pick a name from the list of people with a certain job, and then click a command button, and have all the rows of information for that person pop up. I don't really want a data validation table

Comment: Thanks, the `With Sheet3` didn't give me an error, but it's still not working unfortunately

Comment: Can you [edit] your question with the revised code you're using, and comment out all error handling?

Comment: @Tara "I want people to be able to pick a name from the list of people with a certain job" is exactly what a data validation table would support.  You can actually have two of these, [where one uses `indirect()` to base its list on the output of the other list](https://www.contextures.com/xlDataVal02.html)... then you would have a [change_event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change) trigger when the second table is filled in.  Take a few minutes and look at those links.  Might change your project a bit, but would have less total user input.

Comment: After looking at the data validation tables a bit, I'll probably switch to that if we can't find a quick fix for the current VBA method! Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure `.Cells(i, 3).Value` is what you want? Add a `MsgBox` or a `Debug.Print` to verify.

Comment: I have edited my code more, and keep getting compile error: for without next. Can you please assist on this error?

Comment: Also, if I add `Next i` then I get an error "Next without for"

Comment: @Tara it may benefit future readers if you post your corrected code as an answer, which you can "accept", and if possible, explain what changes were made.